# How does WhatsApp technically get the phone number?

Tags: android

I've got a SIM card where android itself is showing unknown as the telephone number.

Therefore also `getLine1Number()` returns an empty `string`.
However, *WhatsApp* is able to read my telephone number perfectly.

I'm wondering how it works (technically).

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Does your app request the READ_PHONE_STATE permission?

Comment: Yes, otherwise I'd get a SecurityException (or similar). There are other SO-question related to this problem - e. g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7268452/best-way-to-retrieve-phone-number?rq=1 However there seems to be a way to do it, since WhatsApp is able to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't. It's not possible for an app to get the phone number. Whatsapp asks for the number manually and it sends you a verification code by sms.

Comment: Well, although this is a logical fallback, I (my girlfriend as well) do not recall getting asked for my number and a SMS. I do not delete any SMS and didn't find an evidence for it. Maybe WhatsApp intercepts this confirmation message and deletes it right away. It seems to have the appropriate permissions in order to do that.

Comment: I'm sure of what I wrote. you can always try different hacks, but those hacks won't be stable and will result in an unprofessional app. and in case some older versions of whatsapp or android were able to do that, they can't anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Retrieving phone number is not always possible and permitted.
Most mobile operators lock this feature in their handsets.

WhatsApp ask for phone number and saves it

You can send an SMS to a server and save it, if user permits.

Answer (score 1):

A solution would be to find the most common phone number in received SMS.

WhatsApp has the permission to do that.

Comment: I've tried to do it via Uri uriSMSURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
        Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI, null, null, null,null);  ... However, it does not seem to save the receivers phone nr; I can only see the senders phone nr

Comment: @Hartok the most common number in received sms? I think that was a delirious answer? Because in received SMS won't be my number else my mother, girlfriend, friend's number :)